# Executing functions in objects

Tags: javascript

Can we execute a function within our object itself? See code below:

```
obj = {
     name:function(){alert("maizere");}
};
```

As `obj.name()` also means the same i.e getting access to an object and executing the function. Why not execute inside the object itself, something like this:

```
obj = {
     name:function(){
         alert("maizere");
     },
     name();
};
```

Since `obj = new obj() == { obj() }` right?

I was unsuccessful when I tried this. Is anything wrong here or am I wrong?

Comment: erm, why would you do that? What goal does it serve?

Comment: Because an object expects only `key : value` pair only.You cannot put an statement there.

Comment: No goal.But just wanted to know because when we create the object using constructor function like var obj=new obj(); is equal to obj={obj();} .So this what made me think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you were trying doesn't make sense.

If you wish to execute a function straight away, you can do the following. This works by converting your function for use as an expression, rather than as a declaration:

```
obj={
  name: (function(){
    alert("maizere");
  })()
};
```

However this is not the same as:

```
obj={
  name: function(){
    alert("maizere");
  }
};

obj.name();
```

Because `this` inside each different function call will be different. With the former `this` wll point to the global object (normally `Window` in browsers) and in the latter `this` will point to `obj`.

Comment: @pebbl your 1st e.g was the one i was thinking of ...Thank u very much sir.Also i m clear now

Answer (score 4):

The following notation:

```
var obj = {};
```

Is called "object literal". It expects a list of key/value pairs, being the properties of the object.

And only that.

Answer (score 1):

An object literal is not a class, so there is no scoping to the root object, similar with the `window` object. Besides, object literals are not syntactically structured with the intent to do this. It is a heterogeneous list key-value pairs. Like this:

```
var o = { a : b };
```

JavaScript doesn't have classes. However, the `with` statement (seldom used) allows this behavior (to access a property or method on an object without specifying the objects root).

```
var obj = { name: function() {} };

with ( obj ) {
    name();
}
```

But this construct should not be used in code as it causes problems. But as an answer to your question, it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Yes definitely something is wrong.

JavaScript Objects consist of name:value pairs, so you are not allowed to break that pattern and do other stuff.
Please have a look at [the details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Data_structures)

Comment: No sir .I found the way exactly i was thinking i.e var obj={name:(function(){alert("")})()}.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a constructor in the sense of class-based languages this could be a better approach:

```
// "class" definition and constructor
var MyObject = function() {
  this.name();
};
// method
MyObject.prototype.name = function() {
  alert("maizere");
};

// create an object instance of your "class"
var obj = new MyObject();
```

Note that Javascript has no classes. However, the term sometimes helps to understand the approach of Javascript constructors.

Comment: what's the difference between class and object.In my view since i m new to programming object is the collection properties and method than what is a class.o thanks for ur post

Comment: There are fundamental differences between classes and objects. Easily said, a class is a group of objects with the same properties. In class-based languages an object is an instance of exactely one class. In JS there are no classes but objects can share a prototype objects which adds its properties to the super object. This is called prototypal inheritance. You should consider to learn and understand these basics first.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has several built-in objects, like String, Date, Array, and more.

An object is just a special kind of data, with properties and methods.

The syntax for accessing the property of an object is:

```
objectName.propertyName
```

example:

```
var message="Hello World!";
var x=message.length;
```

The value of x, after execution of the code above will be:
12

Note how message is the object.

Here's another example where you instantiate the object using new, and add properties to it.

```
person=new Object();
person.firstname="John";
person.lastname="Doe";
person.age=50;
person.eyecolor="blue";
```

Now, here's a class example:

```
function HelloWorld(hour)
{
  // class "constructor" initializes this.hour field
  if (hour)
  {
    // if the hour parameter has a value, store it as a class field
    this.hour = hour;
  }
  else
  {
    // if the hour parameter doesn't exist, save the current hour
    var date = new Date();
    this.hour = date.getHours();
  }

  // display greeting
  this.DisplayGreeting = function()
  {
    if (this.hour >= 22 || this.hour <= 5) 
      document.write("Goodnight, world!");
    else
      document.write("Hello, world!");
  }  
}
```

In this example, HelloWorld is the class.